# Find code in a string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, substring

I am working on a c++ project that takes a script, highlights the text with html spans and outputs it in a GTKMM window. I have it working, but I want to make an algorithm that registers the code instead of using a vector of keywords.
(I know there are websites and stuff to do it for me, but I just want to make this software).

I am now working on highlighting UnityC#, and I've got a problem that me myself and my coding teacher can't seem to fix. (My teacher did not take hours to check what was wrong, but we have looked at it for a while).

I look for all periods and put them in a vector, then I loop through the vector and try to get the right substring. I start the substring on the position of the period + 1 so I don't include the period. Then I want to end the substring when the next period comes, so I check when it finds another period starting from the the beginning of the word. The first time it works and it prints "transform", but the second time it prints "position.x; var a=1" and the third time it prints "x; var a=10;".

```
std::vector<std::size_t> positions;
std::string pats = "GameObject.transform.position.x; var a=10;";
std::size_t pos = 0;

while(pats.find(".", pos) != std::string::npos)
{
    std::size_t found = pats.find(".", pos);
    if(found != std::string::npos)
    {
        positions.push_back(found);
    }
    pos = found+1;
}

for(int i = 0; i &lt; positions.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout&lt;&lt;pats.substr(positions[i]+1, pats.find_first_of(".", positions[i])-1)&lt;&lt;endl;
}
```

I understand it will mess up on the x because it has a semi-colon behind it instead of period, but I don't understand why it messes up the position as well, please help :)

Regards,
Dani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I'm stupid. I read the substring function wrong and thought I had to give the end position rather than the size.

```
    std::vector<std::size_t> positions;
    std::string pats = "GameObject.transform.position.x; var a=10;";
    std::size_t pos = 0;

    while(pats.find(".", pos) != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::size_t found = pats.find(".", pos);
        if(found != std::string::npos)
        {
            //std::cout<< pats.substr(found+1)<<endl;
            positions.push_back(found);
        }
        pos = found+1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++)
    {
        std::size_t start_pos = positions[i]+1;
        std::size_t end_pos = pats.find_first_of(".", positions[i]+1);
        std::cout<<pats.substr(start_pos, end_pos-start_pos)<<endl;
    }
```